# Change allowedit on statement

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I'm trying to change allowedit value on a single field but can't get into it. 
This is my actuall code but I get error:
Okay did rebuild the models and it's fine

```
  [ExtensionOf(formStr(ProdParmReportFinished))]
  final class ProdParmReportFinishedWG_Extension
 {
public void init()
{
    next init();

    ProdTable prodTable;


    select firstOnly RecId from prodTable
        where prodTable.InventRefType != InventRefType::None
           && prodTable.ProdId == prodTable.InventRefId
           && prodTable.ProdStatus != ProdStatus::ReportedFinished;

    prodParmReportFinished_ds.object(fieldNum(ProdParmReportFinished, EndJob)).allowEdit(prodTable.RecId != 0);
}

 }
```

Comment: Where did you place your code?

Comment: i created a new class for it im working with extensions

Comment: It depends on what exactly you extended: form, form datasource  or form control. e.g. ExtensionOf(FormDatasourceStr(<FormName>,<DataSourceName>))]

Comment: I extended only form and the datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are working with extension try something like this

```
[PostHandlerFor(formStr(YourForm), formMethodStr(YourForm, YourMethod))]
    public static void YourForm_xxx(XppPrePostArgs args)
    {
        FormRun sender = Args.getThis();
        sender.control(sender.controlId(formControlStr(YourForm, YourDatasource_Field))).allowEdit(false);
    }
```

With the right click and select **copy event handler method** the correct structure of the method is copied to you, then you enter your code

Comment: Thank you, gonna try it at tomorrow. So I can use this in my statement ? Could you please check my other open thread about verification process ?

Comment: I got 3 errors. Invalid token 'sender' , ' sender' noot found in this scope and expected "." after- Validating)]

Comment: it seems that you did not create the event handler method correctly

Comment: I actually missed class extension so I had no final class. Right now I have something like this.
  prodParmReportFinished_ds.object(fieldNum(ProdParmReportFinished, EndJob)).allowEdit(prodTable.RecId != 0);

But I get errors on next init() method. The form with name ProdParmReportFinished could not be opened.

Error executing code: <empty class> object does not have method 'runbase'.